# Mercurial clone fails with The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: windows-7, mercurial, clone

I'm trying a release:perform for my Maven application and it fails when is doing a Mercurial checkout as part of the process. Trying the same command from the command prompt, fails but provides more details:

```
hg clone -r Simple-Marauroa-0.02.05 https://javydreamercsw@bit
bucket.org/javydreamercsw/simple-marauroa-java "Z:\NetBeans\Simple Marauroa\Simp
le Marauroa Java\Simple Marauroa Parent\target\checkout"
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 226 changesets with 3379 changes to 2264 files
updating to branch default
abort: Z:\NetBeans\Simple Marauroa\Simple Marauroa Java\Simple Marauroa Parent\t
arget\checkout\Simple Marauroa Parent/Card Game Interface DataBase Implementatio
n/src/main/java/com/reflexit/magiccards/core/storage/database/controller/CardCol
lectionHasCardJpaController.java: The system cannot find the path specified
```

At first I thought that the file was not in the repository, but it is. If you wonder Z, is an USB drive, but I have been able to release smaller projects from the same drive. Performing the same command on my desktop works fine.

This is done on Windows 7 and it seems related the long path I guess.

Any idea?

Comment: just a wild guess, the path is too long? Windows has a path-length limit.

Comment: I suspect is related to the long class path. I'll try passing the workingDirectory parameter with a local, shorter path and see how it goes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the workingDirectory parameter with a local, shorter path like C:\checkout, did the trick.

Comment: yes a shorter path solves the error

its kinda weird , it says file not found .

There should have been better error reporting ( fogcreek team - a possible new item for next release .. )

Comment: One reason not to use mercurial ... this bug is so annoying!